Places | Recent Document - Docs don't open in correct app
I'm using Mate 24.04, but this same problem occurred with 22.04 and the last 23 releases.
Clicking on Places | Recent Documents often opens Geany (a text editor) instead of the appropriate app. One example is deb files. Some that do work are Libre Office files.
The files open correctly when double-clicked in the file manager.
What do I change to fix this?

Please also ask at https://ubuntu-mate.community/. The Ubuntu MATE developers are present there.

Does the problem persist when you set the file association in the file manager (I guess on Mate in Right-click menu, properties, "Open with"  tab, which is where you set associations permanently).

Update - the do open correctly in the file manager.
